# How to perform Post-Hoc tests (including tukey and Gammel-Howell) on imputed data using MICE

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice, tukey, posthoc

I would like to perform post-hoc tests on imputed data using MICE in R.
Typically MICE imputes data which is converted to long data to calculate total scores and can be converted back into MIDS elements. Analysis is then conducted over a MIRO element after which analysis can be pooled.

However, I am not able to get it running for post hoc tests including Tukey and Gammel-Howell. Would someone be able to help?

```
IMP <- mice(data, m=5, maxit=10)
IMP_long <- data.frame(complete(IMP, include=TRUE, action= 'long')
IMP_mids <- as.mids(IMP_long, where = NULL, .imp='.imp', .id = '.id'
fit <- with(IMP_mids, expr=lm(total_score ~ GroupingVariable))
```

The grouping variable consists of 3 groups which I would like to compare pairwise. Namely 1vs2, 2vs3 and 1vs3.

```
summary(pool(fit))
```

-> this gives comparisons between two groups, relative to the intercept. Similarly by using contrasts before creating model

Someone who knows how to compare the three groups in one analysis with tukey and/or gammel-howell?

Thanks in advance!!